# download multiple files base on list of directory in notepad

Tags: batch-file

How can I download multiple files in ftp using batch script. I have a list of files in notepad with the exact directory and I want to iterate them to download each of files. Furthermore, folder and sub-folders should be created upon download.

Please help.

Comment: Try [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) for Windows or [URL2File](http://www.chami.com/free/url2file_wincon.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use the scripting function of FTP.exe.

Put the following batch file in your downloads directory, along with the list of files to be downloaded. Change `UserName` to the username you will use, `PassWord` to the password you will use, `ftp.site.com` to the name of the ftp site you'll be downloading from, and `filelist.txt` with the name and path of the file that the list of files to be downloaded is being kept in.

`makescript.bat`

```
:: Set needed Variables
set ftpUserName=UserName
set ftpPassword=PassWord
set ftpSite=ftp.site.com
set filelist=filelist.txt
set script=script.txt

if exist script.txt del script.txt

:: Create Script
echo connect %ftpSite%>> %script%
echo %ftpUserName%>> %script%
echo %ftpPassWord%>> %script%

for /f "tokens=0" %%x in (%filelist%) do (
  echo cd %%~px>> %script%
  if "%%~xx"=="txt" (
    echo ascii>> %script%
  ) else (
    echo binary>> %script%
  )
  echo get %%~nxx>> %script%
)

echo quit>> %script%
```

The above assumes that there are no spaces in the paths or filenames, and that the file with the names and paths of the files to be downloaded is in this form:

```
\path\to\file\file.exe
```

Run `makescript.bat`, then type, or add the following line to a batch file:

```
ftp -s:script.txt
```

FTP will log on to the ftp site, send the username and password, change directories, then download a file, change directories, then download another file. This will repeat until all the files have been downloaded.